# GitHub Workflow with 'pull_request_target' as trigger event (security risk)

Tags: github, github-actions

currently i try to implement a github action (workflow) to add a comment to new pull request.

I checked some blog post (https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/) regarding the event trigger `pull_request_target` which causes that the workflow run inside my repository.

My takeaway is dont use `- uses: actions/checkout@v2` which can result in untrusted code execution.
My idea is to download the markdown file which i want to add as a comment from my repo (main branch).

What are you thinking is this still a security risk?

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Checklist
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened

jobs:
  welcome:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/org/repo/main/markdown-file.md -o markdown-file.md
            const fs = require('fs');
            const body = fs.readFileSync('markdown-file.md')
            await github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: body.toString()
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a security risk. You're getting the file from a known vetted source and not executing it (just reading it) so it's not vulnerable to the problems in the blog post.

Also, if you read closely, there's no problem with using the `checkout` action either. For example, you could checkout the code and then grep it for certain values or run a linter on it.

It only becomes a security risk if you execute the checked out code using something like `npm install` or some other build script.

See [https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/#:~:text=of%20the%20PR.-,Having%20said%20that,-%2C%20mixing%20pull_request_target%20with](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/#:%7E:text=of%20the%20PR.-,Having%20said%20that,-%2C%20mixing%20pull_request_target%20with) for the specific part of your article which talks about this.